# sort string containing numbers in ruby/rails

Tags: ruby, string, ruby-on-rails-3, integer

I want to sort all my locations depending on how many facebook likes they have. But `facebook_likes` is not an `integer`, it is a `string`.

This is the rails code I use:
`@locations = Location.order("facebook_likes ASC").all`

Right now I get something like this:

- 10
- 100
- 201
- 2
- 304
- 400000
- 50
- ...

How can I sort depending on the value, so that the location with the most checkins is on the top. Is this solution with using strings instead of integers flawed form the beginning?

thx for your help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
@locations = Location.all.sort { |a, b| b.facebook_likes.to_i <=> a.facebook_likes.to_i }
```

or

```
@locations = Location.all.sort_by { |a| -(a.facebook_likes.to_i) }
```

Comment: thx! But what do you think, should I change the database model to integer? I chose string because I am worried about saving numbers with are too big for integer.

Comment: @lukas...I think your data model is correct if you anticipate more than 10 digits as facebook_likes..otherwise integer is the way to go..but I think ordering by `facebook_likes` in the database level itself should give you the correct ordering..are you sure the ordering is not correct in case of your code?

Comment: also try the sql command(in your database terminal) `select * from locations order by facebook_likes asc` and analyse the result.

Comment: @lukas..you mean in your code itself, the ordering is correct?